# Google Search Position Regex

Tags: c#, regex

I am trying to get the search position of keywords in google using below regex:

```
 string lookup = "(<h3 class=\"r\"><a href=\")(\\w+[a-zA-Z0-9.-?=/]*)";
```

But this is not working for urls having hypens(-) like:

www.example-xyz.com

Can anyone help me to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Escape your hyphen with backslash and escape that escaping backslash with another backslash:

```
string lookup = "(<h3 class=\"r\"><a href=\")(\\w+[a-zA-Z0-9.\\-?=/]*)";
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried it but its **not working as well**. Its only matching "http".. Any other fix?

Comment: Also add a colon to brackets: `"(<h3 class=\"r\"><a href=\")(\\w+[a-zA-Z0-9.\\-?=/:]*)"`

Answer (score 1):

Since `-` means a range within a `[]`, you need to escape it with a backslash.

```
string lookup = "(<h3 class=\"r\"><a href=\")(\\w+[a-zA-Z0-9.\-?=/]*)";
```

By the way, there are many questions on stackoverflow about matching urls with regex, search tags `[regex]` and `[url]` to have a look if you want a more refined regex.

Comment: Sorry no luck.. It is now throwing "Unrecognized escape sequence error".

Comment: @Himanshu: It's basic C#.  You need two "\\" in order to produce one for the regex parser to use.

Comment: I tried it john but its only matching "http" not complete url.

Answer (score 1):

Read a decent book on Regular Expressions, like [Jeffrey E.F. Friedl's "Mastering Regular Expressions"](http://www.google.com/search?q=Jeffrey+Friedl+Mastering+Regular+Expressions&oq=Jeffrey+Friedl+Mastering+Regular+Expressions).

Not only it will show you that the `-` makes a character range in a character class -

```
[a-z]
```

and so must be escaped -

```
[a\-z]
```

or put at the beginning -

```
[-az]
```

or at the end -

```
[az-]
```

when meant verbatim, but also that it is usually a mistake to parse such markup (a context-free language, in [Chomsky](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chomsky_hierarchy) terms) with one Regular Expression alone.

You are looking for a markup parser (like BeautifulSoup or lxml, but in C#), and [RFC 3986, Appendix B](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#appendix-B) for a proper URI-matching expression instead.

Comment: +1 Excellent answer. And  [MRE3](http://www.amazon.com/Mastering-Regular-Expressions-Jeffrey-Friedl/dp/0596528124 "Mastering Regular Expressions (3rd Edition)") is really the _only_ book that fully explains regex. I second that recommend.